# Typescript - Importing a Module - Cannot Find Module

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have this schema in file `data.ts`

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const DataSchema = new Schema(
    {
        id: Number,
        message: String,
    },
    { timestamps: true }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model('Data', DataSchema);
```

When I try to import this in my index.js as :

`const Data = require('./data');`

I keep seeing this error:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:584
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module './data'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:508:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
```

Any ideas why this is.

I've tried doing:

`export const data = mongoose.model('Data', DataSchema);`

then importing with `import { data as Data } from './data'`

But that also returns the following error:

```
import { data as Data } from './data'
       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at new Script (vm.js:80:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:274:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:326:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:664:28)
```

Comment: you have `data.ts` typescript file which you are importing in `index.js` javascript file? O_o

Comment: Right - updated both to .ts however still get the same errors when I try both as in my question

Comment: how you are executing `index.ts` file?

Comment: With `node index.ts`

Comment: Typescript is a superset of JavaScript. Node does not understand typescript files. You need to first convert typescript files to JavaScript and then use generated `index.js` file to run your program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Quick solution:

Use `ts-node` to run your TypeScript files directly

```sh
npm install --dev ts-node
```

Start a node process with this command:

```sh
node -r ts-node/register index.ts
```

Make sure your `package.json` should contain something like these:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "mongoose": "^5.6.10",
    "typescript": "^3.5.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "ts-node": "^8.3.0"
  }
}
```

#### About TypeScript:

1. `TypeScript` actually is a superset (not a subset) of JavaScript.
   [image: typescript]
2. `.ts` files must be compiled into JavaScript before running on any JavaScript environment (NodeJS, browser,...).
3. Normally in a TypeScript project, we will have a `build` command in `package.json`, which will compile your `.ts` files into `.js` files, follow with a `start` command to start a node process with compiled `js` file:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc index.ts",
    "start": "node index.js",
    "start:dev": "node -r ts-node/register index.ts"
  }
}
```

4. Or you can run `.ts` files directly with [ts-node](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node).

Comment: Thanks - much clearer. So basically I have having issues because I'm using typescripts style of importing and exporting but not actually compiling it into JS?

Comment: Yes, NodeJS only work with JS, and TS actually has something more just than import/export [module system](https://auth0.com/blog/javascript-module-systems-showdown): [type-system](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html), [decorators](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html),...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using typescript try importing like this :

```
import { Data} from "./Data";

let myData= new Data();
```

Comment: `data` is user created file. You cannot import it using `'data'` as this will look in global or node_modules only. For user created modules, you need to provide relative or absolute path of the file. e.g. `'./data'` or `'/path/to/module/data'`

Comment: Edited my answer. Please check

Answer (score -3):

You need to export your model like this,

```
const Data = mongoose.model('Data', DataSchema);

export default Data;
```

And can import it in any file like,

```
import Data from "./Data";
```